# Resize GIMP 2.8 window on Ubuntu 13.10

Tags: workspaces, gimp

I had to use GIMP for the first time on Ubuntu 13.10 a few days ago and its window looks pretty weird. It occupies a full workspace and a third of the workspace below:

[image]

[image]

But it can not be maximised (note the missing button) neither can it be resized. How can I adjust the GIMP window so that it occupies only one workspace? Thanks.

Update: the output of `sudo aptitude show gimp`:

```
Package: gimp                            
State: installed
Automatically installed: no
Version: 2.8.6-1ubuntu1.1
Priority: optional
Section: graphics
Maintainer: Ubuntu Developers <ubuntu-devel-discuss@lists.ubuntu.com>
Architecture: amd64
Uncompressed Size: 15.7 M
Depends: libgimp2.0 (>= 2.8.6), libgimp2.0 (<= 2.8.6-z), gimp-data (>= 2.8.6), gimp-data (<= 2.8.6-z), python-gtk2 (>=
         2.8.0), libgdk-pixbuf2.0-0 (>= 2.24.1), libaa1 (>= 1.4p5), libbabl-0.1-0 (>= 0.1.10), libbz2-1.0, libc6 (>= 2.15),
         libcairo2 (>= 1.10.2), libdbus-1-3 (>= 1.0.2), libdbus-glib-1-2 (>= 0.88), libexif12, libfontconfig1 (>= 2.9.0),
         libfreetype6 (>= 2.2.1), libgegl-0.2-0 (>= 0.2.0), libglib2.0-0 (>= 2.37.3), libgs9 (>= 8.61.dfsg.1), libgtk2.0-0
         (>= 2.24.10), libgudev-1.0-0 (>= 146), libjasper1, libjpeg8 (>= 8c), liblcms1 (>= 1.15-1), libmng1 (>= 1.0.10),
         libpango-1.0-0 (>= 1.29.4), libpangocairo-1.0-0 (>= 1.29.4), libpangoft2-1.0-0 (>= 1.29.4), libpng12-0 (>=
         1.2.13-4), libpoppler-glib8 (>= 0.18.0), librsvg2-2 (>= 2.14.4), libtiff5 (> 4.0.0-1~), libwebkitgtk-1.0-0 (>=
         1.3.10), libwmf0.2-7 (>= 0.2.8.4), libx11-6, libxcursor1 (> 1.1.2), libxext6, libxfixes3, libxmu6, libxpm4, zlib1g
         (>= 1:1.1.4), python:any (>= 2.7.1-0ubuntu2), python2.7
Recommends: ghostscript
Suggests: gimp-help-en | gimp-help, gimp-data-extras, gvfs-backends, libasound2
Conflicts: gimp
Breaks: gimp-plugin-registry (< 4.20120506), gimp-plugin-registry (< 4.20120506)
Replaces: gimp-plugin-registry (< 4.20120506), gimp-plugin-registry (< 4.20120506)
Provides: gimp-helpbrowser, gimp-python
Description: The GNU Image Manipulation Program
 GIMP is an advanced picture editor. You can use it to edit, enhance, and retouch photos and scans, create drawings, and
 make your own images. It has a large collection of professional-level editing tools and filters, similar to the ones you
 might find in Photoshop. Numerous fine-control settings and features like layers, paths, masks, and scripting give you
 total control over your images. 

 Many image file formats are supported, including JPEG, Photoshop (.psd), and Paint Shop Pro (.psp) files. It can also be
 used to scan and print photos. 

 To open files remotely (like over HTTP), install the gvfs-backends package. 

 To use a MIDI device (like a musical keyboard) as an input controller in GIMP, install libasound2 and read the how-to at
 /usr/share/doc/gimp/README.MIDI
Homepage: http://www.gimp.org/
```

Comment: This is not the default GIMP theme. Did you install a different theme? Where did you install Gimp from?

Comment: See the update to the question, I am installing from the Ubuntu repository. I have not installed any themes for GIMP.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest you to try to reinstall GIMP using the following commands in terminal:

1. Uninstall GIMP:

   ```
   sudo apt-get purge gimp*
   ```
2. Delete `~/.gimp-2.8` directory (you can make a backup first) which may contain others GIMP configuration files .
3. Install GIMP again:

   ```
   sudo apt-get install gimp
   ```

Those images from your question don't look as GIMP should, after a clean installation.

Comment: Same thing after re-installing. If GIMP is not supposed to look this way after installation, is there any sort of external user settings messing up with it?

Comment: I just can't understand why maximize button is missing. What is happen if you press Ctrl+Super+Up?

Comment: Nothing happens.

Comment: Again this is strange, because Ctrl+Super+Up should maximize the window. Is this happen with other apps?

Comment: No, this is only with GIMP, all other windows behave as they should.

Comment: @LuísdeSousa And are you sure that you used `purge gimp*` (purge, not remove and star at the end of gimp) to uninstall Gimp before to install it again?

Comment: Yes: `history | grep gimp
 1280  sudo apt-get purge gimp*
 1281  sudo apt-get install gimp`

Comment: Are you using a PPA for gimp or it's direct from the software center?

Comment: What if you try to delete `~/.gimp-2.8` directory? (you can make a backup first)

Comment: Finally! It got back to normal once I deleted `~/.gimp-2.8`. Please include that in your answer so I can accept it.

Comment: @LuísdeSousa Done!

Answer (score 0):

This is Linux, not Windows, so reinstalling a program doesn't blindly reset the user data and rarely fixes problems.

To reset Gimp windows, just use `Edit>Preference>>Window management` and click `Reset saved windows positions to default values`.

If that doesn't work (but it should) or if the windows positions make it hard to use (windows positioned off-screen), you can also just erase the `sessionrc` file in your [Gimp profile](http://www.gimp.org/tutorials/GIMPProfile/).